# EADDRINUSE Error Keeps on being Generated on Every Save

Tags: node.js

I am using node with vue.js as front-end and Express as back-end. I am furthermore using nodemon. Everything has been working properly until 1 hour ago. Since then, every time I save my code, express crashes with the following error (4000 being my port used):

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::4000

I am required to kill the process (kill -15 PID) and then re-start the server, which re-crashes again upon saving the code. Please note that I haven't launched any new processes or applications since that time.

Edit: I have also noticed that if I run pgrep node, I obtain a list of a dozen processes. Is this normal?

How could this happen?

Comment: Does nodemon use SIGTERM to kill your process? It's possible your process is not properly responding to kill signals so that it can clean up resources and exit. The SIGTERM signal is handled by node for you, so it makes sense that it works when you use it to kill the process manually.

Comment: No, a dozen processes is not expected for a single application unless your process is running as a cluster or forks. I would expect two processes, one for your application and another for the nodemon daemon. Some other build tools for node also spawn daemons in the background to do work (like the typescript compiler), so there could be more. It's probably worth looking at the command associated to those node processes using `ps`, you might have some zombie nodemon processes that are also trying to "restart" your process.

Comment: Thank you Jake. I have added process.on('SIGTERM') but that did not seem to help. Not sure if this is the appropriate way to have nodemon use that signal. Yes it appears that I do have zombie processes running.

Comment: Was the signal handler called? If you are handling the signal yourself then you need to also do the work to make the process exit. Ideally you would close all open resources and let nodejs exit on it's own. You could call `process.exit()` to simply end the process, but that's not very graceful. The nodemon documentation has some information on [gracefully handling the kill signals it sends](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#gracefully-reloading-down-your-script). You could also avoid signal handlers altogether, just make nodemon use the SIGKILL signal for unequivocal and forceful termination.